Referencing one bean inside another in Camel YAML DSL
I am using Camel YAML DSL to connect to an IBM MQ queue to receive messages. I am facing issues while creating the connection factory for IBM MQ to be used in the JMS component. The standard java code to create the connection factory is:
    MQQueueConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    mqConnectionFactory.setHostName("localhost");
    mqConnectionFactory.setPort(1414);
    mqConnectionFactory.setQueueManager("QM1");
    mqConnectionFactory.setChannel("CHANNEL");
    mqConnectionFactory.setTransportType(CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    
    UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
    userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername("username");
    userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword("password");
    
    CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    ccf.setTargetConnectionFactory(userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter);
    ccf.setSessionCacheSize(500);
    ccf.setReconnectOnException(true);

I have created the same beans in camel yaml DSL as:
    - beans:
      - name: mqConnectionFactory
        type: "#class:com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
        properties:
          hostName: localhost
          port: "1414"
          transportType: "1"
          channel: CHANNEL
          queueManager: QM1
      - name: userCredsConnectionFactory
        type: "#class:org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter"
        properties:
          username: username
          password: password
          targetConnectionFactory: '#bean:{{mqConnectionFactory}}'
      - name: wmqCachingConnectionFactory
        type: "#class:org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
        properties:
          sessionCacheSize: "500"
          reconnectOnException: "true"
          targetConnectionFactory: '#bean:{{userCredsConnectionFactory}}'

However, I am getting an exception stacktrace as:
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Error pre-parsing resource: wmqtoamqcamelroutetemplate.yaml
    at org.apache.camel.dsl.yaml.YamlRoutesBuilderLoader.preParseRoute(YamlRoutesBuilderLoader.java:975) ~[camel-yaml-dsl-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoutesLoader.findRoutesBuilders(DefaultRoutesLoader.java:163) ~[camel-base-engine-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoutesLoader.findRoutesBuilders(DefaultRoutesLoader.java:101) ~[camel-base-engine-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spi.RoutesLoader.findRoutesBuilders(RoutesLoader.java:133) ~[camel-api-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spi.RoutesLoader.loadRoutes(RoutesLoader.java:85) ~[camel-api-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at com.maersk.relaystream.service.CamelRouteHandler$1.configure(CamelRouteHandler.java:74) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.checkInitialized(RouteBuilder.java:788) ~[camel-core-model-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.configureRoutes(RouteBuilder.java:733) ~[camel-core-model-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.prepareModel(RouteBuilder.java:649) ~[camel-core-model-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.addRoutesToCamelContext(RouteBuilder.java:667) ~[camel-core-model-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.addRoutes(AbstractCamelContext.java:988) ~[camel-base-engine-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at com.maersk.relaystream.service.CamelRouteHandler.createCamelRoute(CamelRouteHandler.java:67) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.maersk.relaystream.service.CamelWatchService$1.eventReceived(CamelWatchService.java:65) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.maersk.relaystream.service.CamelWatchService$1.eventReceived(CamelWatchService.java:54) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.internal.WatcherToggle.eventReceived(WatcherToggle.java:49) ~[kubernetes-client-6.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.AbstractWatchManager.eventReceived(AbstractWatchManager.java:191) ~[kubernetes-client-6.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.AbstractWatchManager.onMessage(AbstractWatchManager.java:268) ~[kubernetes-client-6.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager.onMessage(WatchConnectionManager.java:113) ~[kubernetes-client-6.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatcherWebSocketListener.onMessage(WatcherWebSocketListener.java:55) ~[kubernetes-client-6.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpWebSocketImpl$BuilderImpl$1.onMessage(OkHttpWebSocketImpl.java:105) ~[kubernetes-httpclient-okhttp-6.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.onReadMessage(RealWebSocket.kt:333) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.readMessageFrame(WebSocketReader.kt:245) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.processNextFrame(WebSocketReader.kt:106) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.loopReader(RealWebSocket.kt:293) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$connect$1.onResponse(RealWebSocket.kt:195) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating bean: userCredsConnectionFactory of type: #class:org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter
    at org.apache.camel.dsl.yaml.deserializers.BeansDeserializer.registerBean(BeansDeserializer.java:118) ~[camel-yaml-dsl-deserializers-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.dsl.yaml.deserializers.BeansDeserializer$BeansCustomizer.configure(BeansDeserializer.java:141) ~[camel-yaml-dsl-deserializers-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.dsl.yaml.YamlRoutesBuilderLoader.preParseNode(YamlRoutesBuilderLoader.java:995) ~[camel-yaml-dsl-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.dsl.yaml.YamlRoutesBuilderLoader.lambda$preParseRoute$6(YamlRoutesBuilderLoader.java:973) ~[camel-yaml-dsl-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.camel.dsl.yaml.YamlRoutesBuilderLoader.preParseRoute(YamlRoutesBuilderLoader.java:973) ~[camel-yaml-dsl-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter': Property 'targetConnectionFactory' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:367) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringInjector.newInstance(SpringInjector.java:71) ~[camel-spring-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringInjector.newInstance(SpringInjector.java:41) ~[camel-spring-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.resolveBean(PropertyBindingSupport.java:1612) ~[camel-support-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.model.BeanModelHelper.newInstance(BeanModelHelper.java:126) ~[camel-core-model-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.dsl.yaml.deserializers.BeansDeserializer.registerBean(BeansDeserializer.java:110) ~[camel-yaml-dsl-deserializers-4.7.0.jar!/:4.7.0]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'targetConnectionFactory' is required
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.afterPropertiesSet(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:120) ~[spring-jms-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    ... 41 common frames omitted

Can someone please help me with the correct syntax of referencing a bean inside another bean?
I have taken the reference of referencing a bean inside another bean from the camel kamelets repository, specifically here: https://github.com/apache/camel-kamelets/blob/main/kamelets/jms-pooled-apache-artemis-sink.kamelet.yaml. But this way does not seem to be working for .camel.yaml routes.
I have also tried using targetConnectionFactory: '#bean:{{mqConnectionFactory}}', but I get the same error with that syntax as well.

Use targetConnectionFactory: '#bean:userCredsConnectionFactory'
Kamelets are special and use {{xxx}} notation due to some dynamism. You can find more about that in the Camel route template / kamelets docs.

I tried using targetConnectionFactory: '#bean:userCredsConnectionFactory', but I get the same error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'targetConnectionFactory' is required
